# Spring data.sql file adds a new record every time I start the app.

Tags: java, sql, spring, postgresql, hibernate

Here's my `application.properties` file:

```
spring.datasource.url= jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/Crypto
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=wololo
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always
```

And here's my `data.sql` file:

```
INSERT INTO crypto(departure, details, lowest_price_date, lowest_price_ever, coin_name, url)
VALUES (null, null, null, 10, 'foooobs', 'http://foo.foo');
```

The problem is every time I restart the app, a new record is added even if it exists from the previous session. I want to initialize the database with data only once and not change it ever.

Any ideas?

Comment: what if you make changes in data.sql file for example add a new record? In this case what should be happen? ignore that record or create it?

Comment: that's how it should work. if you are thinking about another behavior it's you who are trying to do smth. wrong :) just change `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto` to `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop` and every time you will re-create your DB. it's perfectly fine for development. if you need one-time init for DB - consider using smth. like `FlyWay` or remove `data.sql` and just run that script manually on your DB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one possible solution is to use fixed `ids` :

```
INSERT INTO 
crypto (id, departure, details, lowest_price_date, lowest_price_ever, coin_name, url)
        ^^
VALUES (1, null, null, null, 10, 'foooobs', 'http://foo.foo');
        ^
```

So what will happen, first you are making `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update` with this solution, if the record not exit then create a new one, if it is exit, then just update the attributes, and not create a new record.

---

Or maybe you can take a look at [flyway](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/plugins/springboot), it is a good tool in such situations.